# How can I use "where not exists" SQL condition in pyspark?

Tags: python, hive, pyspark, airflow, apache-spark-sql

I have a table on Hive and I am trying to insert data in that table.
 I am taking data from SQL but I don't want to insert id which already exists in the Hive table. I am trying to use the same condition like where not exists. I am using **PySpark** on Airflow.

Comment: you accept the answer whenever you want

Answer (score 8):

The `exists` operator doesn't exist in Spark but there are 2 [join operators](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join) that can replace it : `left_anti` and `left_semi`.

If you want for example to insert a dataframe `df` in a hive table `target`, you can do :

```
new_df = df.join(
    spark.table("target"),
    how='left_anti',
    on='id'
)
```

then you write `new_df` in your table.

`left_anti` allows you to keep only the lines which do not meet the join condition (equivalent of `not exists`). The equivalent of `exists` is `left_semi`.

Comment: First time I see this. Do not need to do df2 = spark.table('table') I assume?

Comment: you can first assign `spark.table()` to a variable df2 of course, but there is no need if you only use the dataframe in one place.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not exist` directly using spark SQL on the dataframes through temp views:

```
table_withNull_df.createOrReplaceTempView("table_withNull")
tblA_NoNull_df.createOrReplaceTempView("tblA_NoNull")

result_df = spark.sql("""
select * from table_withNull 
where not exists 
(select 1 from 
tblA_NoNull 
where table_withNull.id = tblA_NoNull.id)
""")
```

This method can be preferred to left anti joins since they can cause unexpected BroadcastNestedLoopJoin resulting in a broadcast timeout (even without explicitly requesting the broadcast in the anti join).

After that you can do `write.mode("append")` to insert the previously not encountered data.

Example taken from [here](https://kb.databricks.com/sql/disable-broadcast-when-broadcastnestedloopjoin.html)

Answer (score -1):

IMHO I don't think exists such a property in Spark. I think you can use 2 approaches:

1. A workaround with the `UNIQUE` condition (typical of relational DB): in this way when you try to insert (in `append` mode) an already existing record you'll get an exception that you can properly handle.
2. Read the table in which you want to write, `outer join` it with the data that you want to add to the aforementioned table and then write the result in `overwrite mode` (but I think that the first solution may be better in performance).

For more details feel free to ask

Comment: Some good info here, but having seen working answers, does it not make sense to adapt the answer, or drop it, or maybe move it to question about "spark unique join"?